# Pytorch:1.2.0 - AttributeError: 'Conv2d' object has no attribute 'weight'

Tags: initialization, pytorch

I am trying to initialise the following weights the following way:

```
def _initialize_weights(self):
    for m in self.modules():
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
            nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight)
            if m.bias is not None:
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
        elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
            nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
```

This gives me the Attribute error. nn.Conv2d definitely has an attribute named 'weight', Not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the attribute you're looking for is `weights`, not `weight`. (*Plural form instead of singular)*
You can visit this link for more information.
https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d